# Override argeparse default value

Tags: python, arguments

I am working on a command line interface and would like to use `multiprocessing` in one of the arguments to select core usage. I am trying to address the issue that when the user doesnt call on the `-c` command for core usage i want to prompt him and ask if he wants to increase core usage from the default of `1`. The problem I am facing is that even after I ask the user for his choice and change the default with `parser.set_default`, the program runs with a core usage of 1. using `parser.get_default` I can see that the default value is what the user selects. yet It still seems to run with 1 core only. I am not pasting all of code, only the relevent parts.

**EDIT:**

The program is a slightly modified version of this script [here](https://github.com/chapmanb/cloudbiolinux/blob/master/utils/s3_multipart_upload.py)

```
parser.add_argument( "-o", "--specifycores", type = int,help= "Allows user to select number of cores for multiprocessing and faster uploads",default = 1 )

@contextlib.contextmanager
def multimap(cores=1):  
    if cores == 1:
        if multiprocessing.cpu_count == 1:
            cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        else:
            print( 'You have {0} cores available.'.format( multiprocessing.cpu_count() ) )
            while yes_no( 'Would you like to increase your core usage' ):
                try:
                    cores = int( raw_input( 'Please enter the number or cores you wish to use: ') )
                except ValueError:
                    print ( 'Please enter a valid number between 1 and {0}'.format( multiprocessing.cpu_count() ) )
                else:
                    if cores > multiprocessing.cpu_count():
                        print ( 'Please enter a valid number between 1 and {0}'.format( multiprocessing.cpu_count() ) )
                    else:
                        parser.set_defaults(specifycores = cores)
                        break
    cores =  parser.get_default('specifycores') 
    print ( 'Uploading with {0} cores at {1}% usage'.format( cores, cores*100/multiprocessing.cpu_count() ) )
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrap(self, timeout=None):
            return func(self, timeout=timeout if timeout is not None else 1e100)
        return wrap

    IMapIterator.next = wrapper(IMapIterator.next)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)
    yield pool.imap
    pool.terminate()

def _multipart_upload(bucket, s3_key_name, tarball, mb_size, use_rr=True,
                      cores=parser.get_default('specifycores')):

    #some code

    with multimap(cores) as pmap:
        for _ in pmap(transfer_part, ( (mp.id, mp.key_name, mp.bucket_name, i, part)
                                      for (i, part) in
                                      enumerate( split_file ( tarball, mb_size, cores ) ) ) ):
            pass
    mp.complete_upload()

def main_for_multipupload(transfer_file, s3_key_name=None, use_rr=True,make_public=False, cores=1):

    '''
    Calls the _multipart_upload function and passes the required parameters to it
    ''' 

    #some code
    mb_size = os.path.getsize(transfer_file) / 1e6
    _multipart_upload(bucket, s3_key_name, transfer_file, mb_size, use_rr,
                      parser.get_default('specifycores'))
#main   

try:
    if args.specifycores > 1:
        if multiprocessing.cpu_count() < args.specifycores:
            main_for_multipupload( file_name, k.key, use_rr=True, make_public=False, cores=1)
        else:
            main_for_multipupload( file_name, k.key, use_rr=True, make_public=False, cores=args.specifycores)
    else:
        main_for_multipupload( file_name, k.key, use_rr=True, make_public=False, cores=parser.get_default('specifycores') )
        end_time = timer()
        print ( 'Time taken - {0} seconds'.format( str( int( end_time - start_time ) ) ) )
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: Are you using the `parser` for anything else.  Why not replace it with something simpler?  That way you can focus on the multiprocessing and context.

Comment: Yes. its a `CLI`, so there are multiple arguments which have their own functionality

Comment: How do you know `cores` is wrong?  When you print it?  When it gets used?  We can't run your code.

Comment: @hpaulj When I run the program without using `-o` , the program checks if the user has moer than 1 core in his system. If yes, he is prompted to enter a value (between 1 and his max number of cores). The number of cores he enters is then chosen for running the process. However even after chosing a legitimate number the program executes with single core usage only.

Answer (score 1):

I have not reviewed all of your code (contrary to your apparent intent, you posted lots of irrelevant code) but you are clearly complicating things by specifying a default value when your stated intention is to not have a default (a value you fall back to if the user doesn't specify one).

You should not specify a default, or put a sentinel value which is outside the domain range;

```
parser.add_option(default = 0)
...
if value == 0:
    value = input ("value: ")
```

Other common no-op defaults are `None` or -1 for values which have to be a natural number; or just don't put a default, and prompt if the value is unset.

Comment: Every function I posted uses a parameter called `cores`. I figured it was relevant